# How to create DataFrame based on multiple JSON files

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have many JSON files inside a folder. All of them have the same structure. Now I want to create the DataFrame, and each JSON file should be the row of this DataFrame.

I know how to create DataFrame based on a single JSON string, but I don't know how to deal with multiple ones:

```
import spark.implicits._
val jsonStr = """{ "key": 111, "value": 54, stamp: "aaa"}"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your JSONs in folder `src/main/resources`

Following code will produce desired result:

```
  private val df: DataFrame = spark.read.json("src/main/resources")
  df.show()

+---+-----+-----+
|key|stamp|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|111|  aaa|   54|
|111|  aaa|   54|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Note that JSON should be machine-readable, not human readable (that means that JSONs shouldn't have new line characters.

Comment: What library should I import for above?

Comment: @Sade it is classes from spark-sql library